# Is there a performance benefit to vendoring dependencies for Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

Based on the official docs, when creating a Google Cloud Function you can choose to either vendor your dependencies or use `go mod`.

Is it known if there a performance benefit, esp. in regards to cold starts, to vendoring your dependencies, instead of using go mod? I unfortunately don't have the opportunity to test this myself.

Comment: No, both produce (essentially) the exact same executable.

Answer (score 0):

All depends where you put the performance. At runtime, there is no difference.

At Build time, there is. Indeed, there is no dependency to download, all are already presents in the code itself. Only the compile time has to be done.

Because the build time is quicker, from April 20th 2020, the function deployment will be also cheaper if you use vendoring mode. Indeed, from this date, the function will use Cloud Build to package and deploy the code, and only 120 minutes are free every day and **per billing account**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did wonder if there were build time benefits of vendoring, like you alluded to. Do you have first hand experience with noticing the performance gain, or is there an article/some docs somewhere that mention this build time perf benefit? Also, thanks for mentioning the cloud build change -- I did not know that.

Comment: I didn't performed these tests with Cloud Function but with Cloud Build. And, because Cloud Function will use Cloud Build for packaging, it's easy to assume that the behavior will be the same!